# How to deploy two Angular5 project on amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, routes, angular5

We need to deploy two different Angular5 project on Amazon S3, like

```
/assets (folder)
/index.html
/clients (another Angular5 folder)
/clients/assets (folder)
/clients/index.html
```

For example my domain is https://example.com

Now, When we try to access root index.html files with https://example.com, it is working fine. but, When we trying to access https://example.com/clients, it returns an error "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'clients'"

One more thing, We have setup 403 redirection on rootpath index.html, because we need to access login page when customer directly hit URL : https://example.com/login
So, When I am trying to access https://example.com/clients, it is automatically redirected on https://example.com

Could anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

The project should be built with this command:

```
ng build --base-href /clients/
```

Option `base-href` indicates that, you what is before the Angular routes.

On the other hand, it's posible you need something like nginx in your server that redirect the request to different projects.